# Javascript validate file field with or without multiple attribute

Tags: javascript, file, input

```
<input name="uploadedfile[]" id="uploadfile" type="file" multiple />

if(document.getElementById("uploadfile").files.length < 1)
{
   alert("You Forgot to select a file");
   return false;
}
```

The above works if the browser supports multiple. But it fails if it does not. Assume because the name is no longer an array. The script will fail (and any code beneath will not be executed).

Is there a solution that works for both compliant and non-compliant browsers?

Comment: I can get around it by a test before the above code checking name uploadedfile for unsupported browsers, then use try / catch for the multiple test. That gets around the error.

Comment: Is there a better solution?